# Extracting value of an array based on the value of another array PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

First time posting here. I want help with a problem I am facing and despite the fact I have searched the web, I couldn't find an answer. So:

I have two arrays, flux and flux_err.

```
 flux = np.array(folded2_lc_binned.flux.value, dtype = 'float')

 flux_err = np.array(folded2_lc_binned.flux_err.value, dtype = 'float')
```

which give me the following results:

```
flux = [0.99996269 1.0000602  1.00017059 1.00002182 1.00007594 0.9999696
 1.00011313 1.00012934 1.00005817 0.99997538 0.99956554 0.99896783
 0.99861592 0.99828523 0.99859077 0.9990297  0.9994933  0.99997085
 1.00000501 0.999919   1.00013363 1.00007749 1.00005972 1.00003064
 0.99999666 1.00003886 1.00002563 1.00004816]

flux_err = [5.34750658e-05 5.23316427e-05 5.29300918e-05 5.33181581e-05
 5.30598314e-05 5.34477987e-05 5.35483605e-05 5.35784012e-05
 5.35678339e-05 5.33819678e-05 5.28453506e-05 5.28792032e-05
 5.28458148e-05 5.31577965e-05 5.36710824e-05 5.40498860e-05
 5.38263520e-05 5.38960178e-05 5.38837160e-05 5.41886097e-05
 5.34210296e-05 5.31687131e-05 5.30733841e-05 5.29602811e-05
 5.38159642e-05 5.35264592e-05 5.34654396e-05 6.24225799e-05]
```

Question: I calculate the minimum value of the array 'flux':

```
Flux min value: 0.9982852339744568
```

How can I calculate the corresponding value in the array 'flux_err' (the value that sits in the same index/position)? I have tried `astype(bool)` but it gives the minimum value of the wanted array (which is not correct) and not the corresponding value that I need.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should consider splitting the questions in two posts.

Comment: Hello Alessandro. Thank you for your advice. I will. Just thought it was better to be more compact. Cheers.

Comment: See this meta post on what's the recommended thing to do in those cases. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using *numpy* as a dependency, you can use the `np.argmin` function, which returns the indices of the minimum values of an array. Then you can use the index returned to index flux_err.

In your case, that would be something along those lines:

```py
min_idx = np.argmin(flux)
min_err = flux_err[min_idx]
```

Notice that `argmin()` may return *multiple* indices in case the minimum value is repeated in the array.

P.S.: Unless I am missing what you mean there, `astype(bool)` is not related to any of this.